# On using '&' and '\\' with align

Tags: math-mode, align, mathjax

When using

```
\begin{align}  
'stuff' 
\end{align}
```

do I use `&`, `\\`, or both to get equations to appear on successive lines.

For example

```
a=b
c=d
 .
 .
 .
e=f
```

Comment: Did you try both options (see title)? Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: I did try both.  It seems only " \\" is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`align` sets a display math environment where `&` is used as alignment points (and separation between alignments) while `\\` is used to separate equations vertically. It works similar to an `array` or `tabular`. You don't have to use `&` in an `align`, but `\\` is necessary to put equations on different lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
               f'(x) &=   e^x (\sin x + \cos x)    \\
  \implies    f''(x) &=  2e^x \cos x               \\
  \implies    f^3(x) &=  2e^x (\cos x - \sin x)    \\
  \implies    f^4(x) &=  2e^x (-2\sin x) = -4 f(x) \\
  \implies    f^5(x) &= -4 f'(x)                   \\
  \implies    f^8(x) &= -4 f^4(x) = 16 f(x)        \\
  \implies f^{10}(x) &= 16 f''(x)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

If you're using MathJax, the same principle holds.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if both were used in this edit of one of my posts:

```
$\begin{align}f'(x)&=e^x(\sin x+\cos x)\\
\implies f''(x)&=2e^x\cos x\\
\implies f^3(x)&=2e^x(\cos x-\sin x)\\
\implies f^4(x)&=2e^x(-2\sin x)=-4f(x)\\
\implies f^5(x)&=-4f'(x)\\
\implies f^8(x)&=-4f^4(x)=16f(x)\\
\implies f^{10}(x)&=16f''(x)\end{align}$
```

I get the impression the &'s aren't really necessary, though.  But when I took one '&' out, it didn't render (presumably I could take them all out).

Comment: This is wrong; `\begin{align}`...`\end{align}` should not appear inside math mode `$`...`$` as it sets itself as a display math construction already.

Comment: You can verify this on [math.se].

Comment: @Werner  I was using mathjax on MSE, and it seems \begin{align}...\end{align} _should_ appear inside math mode.  Otherwise I get a 'misplaced &' error message.

Comment: So how do you explain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu8g3.png) (typed on [math.se])?

Comment: @Werner ok.  I went back and removed the '$'s.  It worked well.    It worked in math mode also though;  but I didn't like where the text around it came out.  Your way appears to be better.